# How to php send result to ajax immediately

Tags: php, ajax

There is a question bothering me, pls help!
I use jquery's ajax to call a php api.

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{type:type,fid:fid,model:'star'},
            url:'Recommend/Star/mark',
            success:function (data) {
                //do something
            },
        ...
      });
```

php code in Recommend/Star/mark method:

```
    error_reporting(0);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    ob_end_clean();

    ob_start ();
    echo json_encode($boolMark);
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(3);
    $this->afterMark($uid, $fid);
```

I want php echo result to ajax immediately, but my codes do not work.

How to make php send result to ajax immediately, and continue to execute remaining code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ....
 echo json_encode($boolMark . "<br>\n");
 // get the size of the output
 $size = ob_get_length();
 // send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
 header("Content-Length: $size");
 header('Connection: close');
 ob_end_flush();
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 /******** background process starts here ********/

 ignore_user_abort(true);

 /******** background process ********/
 set_time_limit(0); //no time limit

 /******** Rest of your code starts here ********/
```

Comment: I answered some minutes before and you Giordano Ricci answered the same, curious :).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call these two functions after `flush()`:

```
session_write_close(); 
fastcgi_finish_request();
```